# Web Crawler not working on Youtube

Tags: python, youtube, web-crawler

I started learning to code in python a week or two ago. I wanted to create something in which you would type in the name of some song title, then the program would return the search page link and the link to the song (inspired by a bot on discord) . I got the first part working, the searchpage link would return just fine but i couldn't figure out how to link the song. So i figured if i could print the first video title that pops up, i would be fine, as most of the times, the first link is the one desired.
So i made a crawler to crawl all the links of the videos, and then i would return the first one. This part doesn't work... However the same crawler code works for other websites. I can't figure this one out...

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib

    def milo():

          User_input = input("Title of Youtube vid - ")

          words = User_input.split()

          list = []

          list.append('+'.join(words))
          print("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + list[0])


          url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + list[0]

          source_code = requests.get(url)
          plain_text = source_code.text
          soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
          for link in soup.findAll('a',"video-title"):
              song = link.get('href')
              list.append('https://www.youtube.com' + song)
              print(list[0])



milo()
```

Comment: Have you actually inspected what you got in `source_code.text ` ? (NOT what you get in your brower)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use variable `list` because this is a reserved python word, instead of this you can use `lst` and try this, this will work

```
# lst instead of list
lst = []

...

for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    lst.append('https://www.youtube.com' + link.get('href'))
print(lst)

# if in inspect document don't find any of .class or #id for any of tags
# we need to get a `tag` that we need for example in our case it is `a`
# and after find our tag that we need and there will be all classes and tags that we need 
# bacause for example youtube make some tags hidden and we don't we it with inspect from chrome/firefox
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link)
```

**Output**

```
Title of Youtube vid - Roots
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Roots
[
'Roots', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUdyuKaGQd4', 
 # many other urls
 ...
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB4oFu4BtQ8'
]
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. How did you get the "yt-uix-tile-link" class? i cant find it in the source code of the search page. How did you know what was required?

Comment: Did. Sorry, i'm new here.